# Remove &zwnj; characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page I have a text area. Inside is some `&zwnj;` characters.

I need these removed.

I know I can use replace to do this but when I access the .html() of the text area they do not appear.

```
console.log($('#my-textarea').html());
```

So doing a replace on the above has to effect.

How can I remove these characters?

---

Edit:

```
$('#my-textarea').html().replace(/\&zwnj;/g,'');
```

The above fails to remove the hidden chars.

Comment: If `#my-textarea` is actually a `<textarea>` element, then you shouldn't be using `html()` at all. Use `val()`

Comment: So how did you use replace?

Comment: Rory - it's actually a div (confusing name i know). .text() also fails to log the hidden chars.

Comment: .replace('x','y') - it'll have no effect tho, as the hidden chars do not log.

Comment: How do you use replace.... Show it... How you use it might be the reason why it is not working

Comment: .replace('/\&zwnj;/g','')

Comment: well that is not a valid regular expression, you have a string, not a reg exp. Place the code in your question.

Comment: .replace(/\&zwnj;/g,'') still fails.

Comment: Put what you are doing exactly in your question....

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: I can conform it's an issue with the hidden char and not the code, as I have replaced a standard character with the same code with no issues.

Comment: and there you go, running the regular expression does not update the .html(), it just updates the string you have.  `var str = foo.html().replace(...);  foo.html(str)`

Comment: Not at all, I update the HTML too, even test by logging. Does not get removed.

Comment: Your edited comment still fails to work. Perhaps if you tested before posting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replace(/&zwnj;/g, '')` didn't work because HTML and javascript use different encodings to represent special characters.

You could use unicode representation to remove this special character.

```js
$('#replace').click(function() {
  var $text = $('#my-textarea');
  
  console.log($text.html())
  
  $text.html($text.html().replace(/\u200C/g, '?')); // ? for demo
  
  console.log($text.html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-textarea">
test test &zwnj;
test test &zwnj;
test test &zwnj;
test test &zwnj;
test test &zwnj;
</div>
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
```

Comment: Yep, great answer Yury! You know what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require html as a value for something, this might do the trick:

```
console.log( $('#my-textarea').text() );
```

The jQuery `.text()` method does a nice job of sanitizing the input, it returns text, only, and strips the rest away.

Comment: Nothing to do with question.

Comment: Glad you took a moment to try to understand what I propose.